# Speed up javascript run time

Tags: javascript, optimization, execution

Although I have reviewed several of previous posts, my rookie capabilities are blind to a solution for speeding up the execution of the following code. There are hundreds of k, and for each k there are (tens)thousands of i and nearSum() has a loop that evaluates testStr.

This code is slow and timing out Chrome – how do I improve the execution?
Before you ask, the only reason for any of the code is ‘because it is working’.  The values for nn are global variables.

```
Function()…
resArrLen = resultArray[k].length;
for (i=0;i<resArrLen;i++)
{
testStr = resultArray[k][i].toString();
resultArray[k][i] = testStr + "'" + nearSum(testStr);
}//end for i
…

function nearSum(seqFrag)
{
var i=0;
var ninj=0;
var seqFragLen=0;
var calcVal=0;
var nn="";

//sum values
seqFragLen = seqFrag.length;
for (i=0; i+1<seqFragLen; i++)
{
nn = seqFrag.substr(i,2);  //gets value
ninj = eval(nn);
calcVal = calcVal.valueOf() + ninj.valueOf();
} //end for i

return calcVal.toFixed(2);

} //end nearSum
```

Comment: Any data example to go with this? It is hard to see any ways to optimize without some data.

Comment: What does `resultArray` contain, and why are you turning it into strings and then using `eval` on parts of it? Unless there is some very specific reason why it has to be done that way, it's quite inefficient.

Comment: As a community we cannot do very much with your post. It is unclear what the composition of your data is. While you give some indication of the quantity of data, a sample is really what was required. The result is that in order to answer this every single answerer would have to compose their own data set, attempt to match it to your shown code, and then attempt to reproduce the speed issue described. That process wastes time. Please try to consider other users when posting so that they can answer. This would be remedied by a small piece of sample data that shows how this code is interacting.

Comment: Every two successive letters (e.g. AT, TG, GA, etc) of string (e.g. ATGAACAAAGGCGCGTTACCT) is evaluated as a a value (e.g. AT = -3.67; AT is a global variable set to the indicated value) and summed - the sum is returned by nearSum.  Each of the i contain a similar string but the string length may change. In this example, the string sums to -122.21 which is the value that nearSum returns. As indicated in original post - no particular reason for any code aside from 'it works' because I am a rookie.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, it appears that you are using 'eval' to convert a string to a number.  That's not how that's intended to be used.  Use 'Number(nn)' or 'parseInt(nn)' instead.

Otherwise, the code is incomplete and with no example data it's difficult to optimize.

Comment: My reply to above applies here as well.

Comment: I see... you're working with DNA.  I you have control over the input data, you could get the biggest performance boost by working with numbers instead of base pair letters, so that you don't have to map strings to values (which requires a 'hash' lookup).  In other words, you need 2 bits to represent the 4 letters, and 4 bits to represent pairs of letters, or values from 0 to 15.  Each value could then be used as an index into an array to get the values that you're summing.

Comment: In any case, if you provide your test data and complete code (or just a working subset that does your calculations), I will optimize it for you.

Comment: Yes DNA, but...thermodynamics which are estimated by nearest neighbor model, so, 16 values for 2-base combinations and sum of serial progression in sequence.  All DNA data is collected and stored as strings of A/T/G/C (as you are aware); so, this is the limitation and the string needs to be converted to numerical data via the model.  The code section I posted is one of the big time factors; the other is managing the large output to DOM (I think).  This is a sequence space problem **big data** with 64 codons for 20 amino acids (aa) - 100aa protein has 61^100 possible DNAs - working with 5-12aas